# Hide whole item until image is load

Tags: angularjs

So, I've got a table displaying some data with ngRepeat:

```
<tr class="item" ng-repeat="media in items | filter: search | orderBy: sortType: sortReverse">
<td>
<img ng-src="{{media.path + 'thumbnail-' + media.filename}}" onimageload>
</td>
<td>
{{media.title}}
</td>
...
```

And a directive for the image onload like this:

```
app.directive('onimageload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now, how do I hide each item until his image is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach: preload the images in the parent directive link, and watch for their onload events there:

```
angular.forEach(scope.items, function(media) {
    var preloaded = new Image();
    preloaded.src = media.path + 'thumbnail-' + media.filename;
    preloaded.onload = function() {
        media.hasLoaded=true;
    };
})
```

and then

```
<tr ng-repeat="media in items" ng-if="media.hasLoaded">.....</tr>
```

The `ng-if` will prevent multiple requests going to the server for the same image, since its contents, including the `<img>` tag, won't render until after the image is already in browser memory.

(Note this doesn't use your `onimageload` directive, as that would involve communicating the hasLoaded variable up to `$parent` , which always makes me feel icky.  Do it once in whatever directive renders your `ng-repeat` instead of instantiating separate directives for each image.)

Comment: Sorry, I started with angular last week... What do you mean by parent directive link? Could you show me the code for the whole directive, with the forEach loop added?

Comment: By "parent" I mean your existing directive that contains scope.items (which  in your approach would have been the parent of each of your `onimageload` directives).

Comment: OK, now I think is working. I had to change the `ng-if` by `ng-show`, though. With `ng-if` it showed nothing...

Comment: By the way, it would be equivalent your approach to this one? `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.visible = true;
                });
            });
        }` And then: `<tr ng-show="visible" ...>` ¿?

Comment: No, that would not be an equivalent approach (afaict yours still depends on separate directives for each `<img>` watching its own element's load from inside the `ng-repeat`; mine sets up the load watchers for all items before the `ng-repeat` is rendered.  The problem with the many individual directives approach is that `.visible` is only on the scope for the image itself; it wouldn't be usable on the `<tr>` above it unless you start mucking about with `$parent`.